# PyObject_CallMethod always returns NULL when dealing with a "complex" script

Tags: python, c++, pandas, embed

I wrote a Python script which is in charge of reading data from an .xlsx file, and then return the result to a C++ program. In synthesis, the pipeline is the following:
C++ program invokes Python script ---> the Python script reads and performs several operations on a dataframe ---> the Python script returns a list to the C++ program.

Here's the Python script (inside the file `constellation_retrieval.py`):

```
from datetime import date 
import time
import requests
from astroquery.mast import Observations
from astropy.coordinates import EarthLocation, AltAz, SkyCoord
import astropy.units as u

import pandas as pd

class Constellation_retrieval():

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def main_method(self):
        
        def getSkyCoord(ra, dec):
            skyCoord = SkyCoord(ra=ra * u.deg, dec=dec * u.deg, representation_type='spherical')
            return skyCoord

        def getAltAz(skyCoord, observerTime, location):
            altAz = skyCoord.transform_to(AltAz(obstime=observerTime, location=location))
            return altAz

        def getAltAngle(altAz):
            alt = (altAz.alt * u.deg).value
            return alt

        def getAzAngle(altAz):
            az = (altAz.az * u.deg).value
            return az

        def getConstellation(name_flamsteed_full):
            name_split = str(name_flamsteed_full).split('-')
            constellation = name_split[1]
            return constellation
    
        # Getting the current date
        today = date.today()
        theTime = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        observerTime = str(today) + " " + str(theTime)
        
        # Getting the current location. It is necessary to be connected to
        # the internet
        location = requests.get('http://ipinfo.io/json').json()
        location = EarthLocation.of_address(location['city'] + ", " + location['region'])
        
        bright_stars = pd.read_excel('bright_stars.xlsx', index_col=False)
        bright_stars.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis=1, inplace=True) 
        
        bright_stars['SkyCoord'] = bright_stars.apply(lambda row : getSkyCoord(row['ra'], row['dec']), axis=1)
        bright_stars['AltAz'] = bright_stars.apply(lambda row: getAltAz(row['SkyCoord'], observerTime, location), axis=1)
        bright_stars['Altitude'] = bright_stars.apply(lambda row: getAltAngle(row['AltAz']), axis=1)
        bright_stars['Azimuth'] = bright_stars.apply(lambda row: getAzAngle(row['AltAz']), axis=1)

        bright_stars = bright_stars.drop(['SkyCoord', 'AltAz'], axis=1)
        bright_stars['Constellation'] = bright_stars.apply(lambda row: getConstellation(row['name_flamsteed_full']), axis=1)
        
        bright_stars = bright_stars[bright_stars['Constellation'] != '']
        bright_stars = bright_stars.reset_index(drop=True)
        
        visible_stars = bright_stars[bright_stars['Altitude'] >= 0]
        not_visible_stars = bright_stars[bright_stars['Altitude'] < 0]
        
        list_of_not_visible_constellations = list(set(not_visible_stars['Constellation'].values))
        visible_stars = visible_stars[~visible_stars['Constellation'].isin(list_of_not_visible_constellations)]
        
        final_visible_stars = list(set(visible_stars['Constellation'].values))
        return final_visible_stars
```

This is the function, written in C++:

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <JuceHeader.h>
#include <Python.h>

void myFunction()
{
    Py_Initialize();

    PyRun_SimpleString("import pandas as pd");
    PyRun_SimpleString("from datetime import date");
    PyRun_SimpleString("import time");
    PyRun_SimpleString("import requests");
    PyRun_SimpleString("from astroquery.mast import Observations");
    PyRun_SimpleString("from astropy.coordinates import EarthLocation, AltAz, SkyCoord");
    PyRun_SimpleString("import astropy.units as u");


    PyObject* pyName = PyUnicode_FromString("constellation_retrieval");
    PyObject* pyModule = PyImport_Import(pyName);

    if (pyModule != NULL)
    {
        PyObject* pyDict = PyModule_GetDict(pyModule);

        PyObject* pyClass = PyDict_GetItemString(pyDict, "Constellation_retrieval");

        if (PyCallable_Check(pyClass)) {
            PyObject* pyInstance = PyObject_CallObject(pyClass, NULL);

            PyObject* pValue = PyObject_CallMethod(pyInstance, "main_method", NULL);
        }
    }


    Py_Finalize();
}
```

However, the pValue is always NULL, despite I tested several times the Python function with no errors. Any help?

Comment: That Python seems to be missing bits, like the `Constellation_retrieval` class.

Comment: @molbdnilo sorry, there was a typo in the code: the class is named Constellation_retrieval, and it is situated in the file constellation_retrieval.py

Comment: Ok, I did several debugs of portion of code: I suspect that the problem resides in reading the .xlsx file

Comment: After several tests: I found out that basic Python libraries are imported and exploited with no issues, while "external" libraries (such as Pandas or Astropy) cause errors. I really don't know what to do :-(